Issues with Data Reading and Writing in a Spring Boot Application Using Separate Data Sources
Previously, I used a single data source for all database operations, and everything worked well. However, after separating the data sources into one for writing and one for reading, I'm encountering issues with some operations. Despite adding the @Transactional annotation, some operations still throw exceptions.
Here is a brief overview of the multiple data source configuration and an example of an operation that is causing errors. Note that this is just one example; several operations are affected.
appliation.properties
#Local Development
spring.profiles.active=dev

spring.application.name=Profiles
app.message=This is the primary Application Property for ${spring.application.name}



# JPA properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

application-dev.properties
#master datasource properties
spring.datasource.master.url=jdbc:mariadb://url:port/db
spring.datasource.master.username=root
spring.datasource.master.password=password

#replica datasource properties
spring.datasource.replica.url=jdbc:mariadb://url:port/db
spring.datasource.replica.username=root
spring.datasource.replica.password=password

#required for multiple datasource
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy

master datasource classes
@Configuration
public class MasterDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.master")
    public DataSourceProperties masterDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource masterDataSource() {
        return masterDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef="auditorProvider")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.pg.ed.pojo"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.pg.ed.repositories.write",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManagerFactoryBean",
        transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager"
)
public class MasterJPAConfiguration {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(masterDataSource)
                .packages("com.pg.ed.pojo")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(@Qualifier("masterEntityManagerFactoryBean") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl();
    }
}

slave data source classes
@Configuration
public class ReplicaDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.replica")
    public DataSourceProperties replicaDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource replicaDataSource() {
        return replicaDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.pg.ed.repositories.read",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "replicaEntityManagerFactoryBean",
        transactionManagerRef = "replicaTransactionManager"
)
public class ReplicaJPAConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean replicaEntityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("replicaDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(masterDataSource)
                .packages("com.pg.ed.pojo")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager replicaTransactionManager(@Qualifier("replicaEntityManagerFactoryBean") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
    }
}

repository interface

public interface StudentReadRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
  

    /**
     * This method will find Student where id=id
     *
     * @param id Student id
     * @return Student
     */
    Student findById(int id);

}

entity class

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Student {
    private int stdId;
    private String stdName;
    private Classes classes;
   

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int stdId) {
        this.stdId = stdId;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "std_id")
    public int getStdId() {
        return stdId;
    }

    public void setStdId(int stdId) {
        this.stdId = stdId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "std_name")
    public String getStdName() {
        return stdName;
    }

    public void setStdName(String stdName) {
        this.stdName = stdName;
    }

    public void setClasses(Classes classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    public Set<StudentClass> getStudentClasses() {
        return studentClasses;
    }

    public void setStudentClasses(Set<StudentClass> studentClasses) {
        this.studentClasses = studentClasses;
    }
}

service class
@Service
public class StudentService implements IStudentService {

    private final StudentWriteRepository studentWriteRepository;



    public StudentService(StudentReadRepository studentReadRepository) {
       
        this.studentReadRepository = studentReadRepository;
       
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Student findById(int id) {
        return studentReadRepository.findById(id);
    }
  
}

controller class
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/students")
public class StudentController {
private final StudentService studentService;

private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

public StudentController(StudentService studentService, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity getOne(@PathVariable int id) {
        Student student = studentService.findById(id);
        StudentDTO studentDTO = convertToDto(student);

        List listClasses = new ArrayList();
        for (StudentClass studentClass : student.getStudentClasses()) {
            DropdownDTO dd = new DropdownDTO(studentClass.getClasses().getValue(), studentClass.getClasses().getLabel());
            listClasses.add(dd);
        }
        studentDTO.setClasses(listClasses);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

 private StudentDTO convertToDto(Student student) {
        StudentDTO studentDTO = null;
        studentDTO = modelMapper.map(student, StudentDTO.class);
        if (student.getClasses() != null) {
            studentDTO.setClassId(student.getClasses().getValue());
        }
        return studentDTO;
    }

}

When I call the method to get a student by ID, I receive the following error
ERROR: Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@1fcf2375 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet to java.util.List.
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.pionlog.edsims.pojo.Classes.classes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
I expect it give me result but it throw exception
